# php. write to file

Tags: php

I am learning php. I want to write string to file, but nothing happens.
How can I debug it? I have experience with python. there I could use terminal 
to try small code snippets, but I don't know how check code in php.

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
$myvar = fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Be sure you have write permissions in the folder you are writing. If you are on unix style OS, permissions should be 777(read write execute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugging in php always starts with turning up error reporting

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);


$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
$myvar = fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

chances are good that you will now see a somewhat descriptive error message. googling php error messages is often helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you really need to use file handlers, just do this:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\nTracy Tanner\n";
file_put_contents($myFile,$stringData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like correct code. Try checking to make sure you have the right file path. An easy way to do this is

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$value = fgets($fh);
echo $value;
fclose($fh);
```